# How to deploy a smartcontract and make a transfer from it in Everscale blockchain

Tags: blockchain, smartcontracts, everscale

I found this [quickstart](https://tonlabs.gitbook.io/ton-sdk/quick_start) guide on how to do it locally. But there is no information about on how I can deploy my smartcontract to devnet or mainnet.

So I changed endpoint:

```js
const client = new TonClient({
    network: {
        endpoints: ["https://net.ton.dev"]
    }
})
```

According to comment, I removed `useGiver`:

```js
// Request contract deployment funds form a local TON OS SE giver
// not suitable for other networks.
// Deploy `hello` contract.
await helloAcc.deploy(/*{ useGiver: true }*/);
```

And got this this error message:

```
Account does not exist. You need to transfer funds to this account first to have a positive balance and then deploy its code
```

How do I fund my account, is there any automatic method like `airdrop`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We added a couple of guides about how to deploy and configure your own giver in developer network. Please, check them out:

Work with devnet with everdev tool - https://github.com/tonlabs/everdev/blob/main/docs/work_with_devnet.md

Configure giver in AppKit - https://tonlabs.gitbook.io/appkit-js/guides/custom_giver

Answer (score 0):

You need to first calculate the contract address in the target chain and then tip it up to 1 EVER for deployment to succeed.

The amount of gas needed depends on the code of the contract, but cannot exceed 1 EVER.

Answer (score 0):

There are no automatic givers in net.ton.dev now. But you can get rubins from here: faucet.extraton.io Also you can create automatic giver in this test network by yourself.